# Saving chat message in MySQL DB, scheme design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm building a pretty simple chat app that allows both 1 on 1 message and chat rooms for groups of people. I'm planning to have one Message table to store all chat messages, each message will also keep the sender ID and receiver ID, in the case of messages sent in a chat room, we also keep the ID of that chat room. Below is the table:

```
Message Table

ID      Message               Sender       Receiver    Chatroom    Timestamp      
1       Hello, David          123          321                     1495330074
2       Hi, Linda             321          123                     1495930032
3       Hi everyone!          456                       999        1495930132
4       What up?              321          123                     1495930192

...
```

Then if I'm user 321, and I want to retrieve my conversation with user 123, I just need to `SELECT * FROM Message WHERE Sender=123 or Receiver=123 or Sender=321 or Receiver=321 and Chatroom IS NULL`

There is one issue with this design - a user can't delete a message that he doesn't want to see any more.

To solve that, I think I can have a separate table to store what messages a user received or sent, like below:

```
User Message Table

ID      UserID               MessageID               
1       123                   1                    
2       321                   1
3       321                   4
...
```

It seems a little redundant, but this way David can delete a message in his conversation with Linda, while Linda can still see full conversation history.

Is there better design of the tables? And is this good practice to throw all chat messages in one giant table? Should I add some index to make query faster?

Comment: When your table gets big, that `OR` will be terribly slow.  Search this forum for 'chat' to see what others are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query.

```
delete from Message
where sender = 123 and user = 321
```

But this will delete all the chat messages between this user and sender. To delete specific message you can use ID

delete from Message
where ID = 1

Comment: That won't work, you should never delete a message in the DB. Like I said, if David delete a message in the conversation between him and Linda, Linda should still see that message.